# crontab i have the error TERM environment variable not set

Tags: bash, shell

im using top command on shell script, when its executed on crontab i have the error TERM environment variable not set.
below my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=`hostname`

echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Check cpu load & Memory with top on $HOST at $(date +%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S)"
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo ""
/usr/bin/top -n 1
echo ""
echo ""
echo "------check zombie process---"
/usr/bin/top -n 1 |grep zombie
echo "-----------------------------"
```

result after crontab script is executed

```
00 14 * * * /home/doug/topcommand.sh > /home/doug/check_`hostname`_`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.log   2>&1
```

TERM environment variable not set.

im expecting a top command result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `top` is batch mode for it to work in a crontab.

Use `/usr/bin/top -b -n 1`

It may also be useful to specify the output width you want with `-w`, e.g., `-w 512` to get very long lines of output.

Ref: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html